# Import error on struct and functions definitions in C

Tags: c, function, debugging, struct, header

I have the following files: the first one is data_structures.c and the second one is the respective header data_structures.h. There is a sort of "circular dependency" problem, because in my .c I defined two functions which use structs as parameters and also in the bodies and in my .h if I'm right I need all the structs definitions in order to let them public and usable from other source files. How can I fix it?

.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void appendResultsList(struct ResultsList* list, char* result){
    struct ResultsListElement *new = malloc(sizeof (struct ResultsListElement));
    new->value = result;
    new->next = NULL;
    list->last->next = new;
    list->last = new;
}

void appendRotationsList(struct RotationsList* list, struct RotationNode* rotation_node){
    struct RotationsListElement *new = malloc(sizeof (struct RotationsListElement));
    new->value = rotation_node;
    new->next = NULL;
    list->last->next = new;
    list->last = new;
}
```

.h

```
#ifndef DATA_STRUCTURES
#define DATA_STRUCTURES
#include "data_structures.c"


struct ResultsList {
    struct ResultsListElement* first;
    struct ResultsListElement* last;
};

struct ResultsListElement {
    char* value;    //il matching
    struct ResultsListElement* next;
};

struct RotationList { //list_el
    char man;
    char woman;
    struct RotationList* next;
};

struct RotationNode {
    struct RotationList* rotation;
    int index;
    int missing_predecessors;
    struct SuccessorsList* successors;
};

struct SuccessorsList {
    struct RotationNode* value;
    struct SuccessorsList* next;
};

struct RotationsList { //free_rotations_list
    struct RotationsListElement* first;
    struct RotationsListElement* last;
};

struct RotationsListElement { //free_rotations_list
    struct RotationNode* value;
    struct RotationsListElement* next;
};

void appendResultsList(struct ResultsList*, char*);
void appendRotationsList(struct RotationsList*, struct RotationNode*);

#endif
```

I think a solution could be define all in data_structures.h (structs + functions) but I think it's not good. I just want the function declaration in my .h and not the definitions. Thanks in advance.

```
In file included from tester.c:6:
data_structures\data_structures.c:5:31: warning: 'struct ResultsList' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
    5 | void appendResultsList(struct ResultsList* list, char* result){
      |                               ^~~~~~~~~~~
data_structures\data_structures.c: In function 'appendResultsList':
data_structures\data_structures.c:6:57: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'struct ResultsListElement'
    6 |         struct ResultsListElement *new = malloc(sizeof (struct ResultsListElement));
      |                                                         ^~~~~~
data_structures\data_structures.c:7:12: error: invalid use of undefined type 'struct ResultsListElement'
    7 |         new->value = result;
      |            ^~
data_structures\data_structures.c:8:12: error: invalid use of undefined type 'struct ResultsListElement'
    8 |         new->next = NULL;
      |            ^~
data_structures\data_structures.c:9:13: error: invalid use of undefined type 'struct ResultsList'
    9 |         list->last->next = new;
      |             ^~
data_structures\data_structures.c:10:13: error: invalid use of undefined type 'struct ResultsList'
   10 |         list->last = new;
      |             ^~
```

And almost the same errors for the other function. It seems the compiler doesn't see the struct definitions in .h even if I included the .h file

Comment: If you get build-errors, then please copy-paste the full and complete build-log (*as text*) into your question. Please [edit] your question. And add comments on the lines where you get the errors (if available).

Comment: I applied the changes that @dbush suggested, but I got errors. I edited the question with errors

Answer (score 2):

You've got the includes backwards.  If you're ever including a .c file, it's almost always wrong.

You want to instead include the .h file in the .c file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "data_structures.h"

void appendResultsList(struct ResultsList* list, char* result){
    struct ResultsListElement *new = malloc(sizeof (struct ResultsListElement));
    new->value = result;
    new->next = NULL;
    list->last->next = new;
    list->last = new;
}

void appendRotationsList(struct RotationsList* list, struct RotationNode* rotation_node){
    struct RotationsListElement *new = malloc(sizeof (struct RotationsListElement));
    new->value = rotation_node;
    new->next = NULL;
    list->last->next = new;
    list->last = new;
}
```

And remove the `#include` from your header file.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I applied the changes you suggested but I still got errors. I edited the question by adding compiling errors.

Comment: @void Did you remember to delete the `#include "data_structures.c"` line in the header file?

Comment: @void Did you `#include "data_structures.h"` in your .c file?

Comment: yes, for both questions. Could be #ifndef the problem? If yes, I cannot delete that statement because I need data structures definition elsewhere (so multiple includes).

Comment: Are you using `DATA_STRUCTURES` in files other than data_structures.h?  Each header should have its own header guard macro defined.

Comment: @dbush nope, the guard macro is unique for that header.

Comment: @dbush nevermind, i was using that macro guard in another file. Thanks a lot!